# python pandas: Remove duplicates by column

Tags: python, pandas

So i have this data :

```
        Evenid  memberid  response
          932   48462         0
          932   65542         1
          947   48462         0
          947   56494         0
          947   62049         0
```

The eventid's repeat and I just want to delete the duplicates and those cells empty. Like the event id should be shown just once. I have tried different solutions but it's not working for me.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("out.csv")
  
m=df.apply(lambda x:dict.fromkeys(x).keys())
pd.DataFrame(m.values.tolist(),index=m.index).T
#data.drop_duplicates(subset='Evenid', keep='first')

print(df)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the other values? What is your desired output?

Comment: I am training a model with this file and i want to see if removing these redundant values can help improve accuracy. @Nick

Comment: Did you check `drop_duplicates` method? `df.drop_duplicates('Evenid')`..

Comment: Yes i did, doesn't work, see the commented line as well tried that too. @Erfan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can sort the DataFrame by Evenid and then replace duplicate values by NaN likewise:

```
df = df.sort_values('Evenid')
df['Evenid'].loc[df.duplicated('Evenid')] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
            Evenid  memberid  response
          932   48462         0
          NaN   65542         1
          947   48462         0
          NaN   56494         0
          NaN   62049         0
```

Comment: This works, thank you!!!! , also I didn't need to have those values sort so i did not use that command.

Comment: Awesome ! If the data is already sorted, then you would only need the second line of code. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** as per comment

```
df['Evenid'] = df.Evenid[~df.Evenid.duplicated()]
```

**Output**

```
    Evenid  memberid    response
0   932.0   48462       0
1   NaN     65542       1
2   947.0   48462       0
3   NaN     56494       0
4   NaN     62049       0
```

If you want to fetch evenid just once and see just the first value in output.
Looking at the example you provided, seems like you don't want to drop duplicates but need the first occurence of evenid.

```
df.groupby(['Evenid'], as_index=False).first()
```

**Output**

```
    Evenid  memberid    response
0   932    48462        0
1   947    48462        0
```

Comment: I need this exported into another csv file and the member id next to it is corresponding to that one event, they should not be removed. Simple an empty cell where the event id is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just want to keep the first unique rows of the dataframe while converting the duplicated rows to nan values.

You can achieve that result with:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset = 'Evenid', keep = 'first'), ['memberid', 'response']] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
Evenid  memberid    response
932     48462.0     0.0
932     Nan         Nan
947     48462.0     0.0
947     Nan         Nan
947     Nan         Nan
```

Comment: No just that one column , i do not want to change the other entries of row against it.

Comment: I've updated the code based on your answer

Comment: Nope, just the event duplicate values as Nan, anyways the answer above by SHivam Roy is correct.